# What *exactly* do the "public", "private" and "protected" methods do?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, encapsulation

Almost all decent resources about OOP in Ruby state the existence of access modifiers - keywords `public`, `private` and `protected` - and show how to properly use them. Fewer go to the extent of explaining that these modifiers are *not* keywords, but are actual methods and that calling them modifies visibility of all methods defined in the future in this particular class. However, I couldn't find any information about *how* they actually do that. Do they change a special internal variable, or do they alter properties of current scope/binding, or do they set some specific interpreter flag, or... or what?

I've done a little research on my own, but it left me even more confused than before. Consider the following code snippet:

```
class Test
    public
    define_method :public_define_method do 
        puts 'Public define_method'
    end

    private
    define_method :private_define_method do 
        puts 'Private define_method'
    end

    public
    def public_def
        puts 'Public def'
    end

    private
    def private_def
        puts 'Private def'
    end
end

t = Test.new

t.public_define_method
t.private_define_method
t.public_def
t.private_def

#Output:
#> Public define_method
#> Private define_method
#> Public def
#> sandbox.rb:29:in `<main>': private method `private_def' called for #<Test:0x00000001cdfd38> (NoMethodError)
```

I always thought as `def` as a sort of optimized syntactic sugar for `define_method` with an additional quirk of creating new variable visibility scope, but, obviously, there seems to be more to it - methods created with `def` are affected by `private`/`public` modifiers, while those created with `define_method` are not. Furthermore, `define_method` [doesn't have](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method) any arguments related to changing method's visibility, which led me to the conclusion that information about it must be stored in classes, not methods themselves - and so should be the flag set by access modifiers. But why then `def` so differs from `define_method`? What happens in the background? Does it check the flag set by access modifier methods and then adds itself into some special hidden register of class' private/protected methods?..

In short, I'm very confused and would be very glad if comeone could please clarify the issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Exactly?

**public** 
http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/public

> With no arguments, sets the default visibility for subsequently defined methods to public. With arguments, sets the named methods to have public visibility.

*Source:*

```
static VALUE
rb_mod_public(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE module)
{
    secure_visibility(module);
    if (argc == 0) {
        SCOPE_SET(NOEX_PUBLIC);
    }
    else {
        set_method_visibility(module, argc, argv, NOEX_PUBLIC);
    }
    return module;
}
```

**private** http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/private

> With no arguments, sets the default visibility for subsequently
>   defined methods to private. With arguments, sets the named methods to
>   have private visibility.

*Source:*

```
static VALUE
rb_mod_private(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE module)
{
    secure_visibility(module);
    if (argc == 0) {
        SCOPE_SET(NOEX_PRIVATE);
    }
    else {
        set_method_visibility(module, argc, argv, NOEX_PRIVATE);
    }
    return module;
}
```

**protected** http://apidock.com/ruby/Module/protected

> With no arguments, sets the default visibility for subsequently
>   defined methods to protected. With arguments, sets the named methods
>   to have protected visibility.

*source*

```
static VALUE
rb_mod_protected(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE module)
{
    secure_visibility(module);
    if (argc == 0) {
        SCOPE_SET(NOEX_PROTECTED);
    }
    else {
        set_method_visibility(module, argc, argv, NOEX_PROTECTED);
    }
    return module;
}
```

---

This doesn't really help with actual applications for this information, however. You may find more real-world applicable information on questions like [What are the differences between "private", "public", and "protected methods"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882754/what-are-the-differences-between-private-public-and-protected-methods) and
[Why does Ruby have both private and protected methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534449/why-does-ruby-have-both-private-and-protected-methods).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. I already know how encapsulation in Ruby works and the results of calling these methods, I'm trying to understand what they do *under the hood*. Please, reread the question. I don't know about C++ much, so digging interpreter's source code by myself would only cause more confusion. Code snippets really help, yet could you please explain more about what `SCOPE_SET` and `set_method_visibility` do? Could the effects of `public` / `protected` / `private` be reproduced in pure Ruby, for instance, or are they hard-coded? Thanks!