# default values for Virtus in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, virtus

I am using virtus(1.0.5) with rails (5.0.2). I am using Virtus for a model since it has validations based on the page being accessed.

My Organization model is as

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

and form created using virtus is as

```
class OrganizationProfileForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include Virtus.model

  attribute :call_center_number, String, default: :org_call_center_number

  validates :call_center_number, presence: true

  def initialize(organization)
    @organization = organization
  end

  private

  def org_call_center_number
    @organization.call_center_number
  end

end
```

Unfortunately, the above code doesn't work

```
Loading development environment (Rails 5.0.2)
2.3.0 :001 > of = OrganizationProfileForm.new(Organization.last)
Organization Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "organizations".* FROM "organizations" ORDER BY "organizations"."id" DESC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
=> #<OrganizationProfileForm:0x007f9d61edd6a8 @organization=# <Organization id: 1, name: "Some name", call_center_number: "4892374928", created_at: "2017-03-29 09:35:22", updated_at: "2017-03-29 09:37:59">>
2.3.0 :002 > of.call_center_number
=> nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to call super() in the initialize method.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the line `private`, as this may be preventing the call to the method `org_call_center_number`. The example given for default values on the [Virtus repo](https://github.com/solnic/virtus#default-values) uses a public instance method, not a private one.

See: [What are the differences between "private", "public", and "protected methods"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882754/what-are-the-differences-between-private-public-and-protected-methods)