# Methods in Controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am looking at a sample Rails application and see some strange things. Well just strange to me because my past experience was with C#.

So in the `ApplicationController` I have a "private" method like this:

```
 private

    def current_cart 
      Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      cart = Cart.create
      session[:cart_id] = cart.id
      cart
    end
```

and then in `orders_controller` class I have another method that in its body it is saying something like:

```
def new
   @cart = current_curt
// ....
end
```

What happened ?  It was private but we can access it? And we don't need to create an instance of it before accessing it ?  Can someone talk a little bit about how the methods in controllers work together in Rails?

Comment: Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534449/why-does-ruby-have-both-private-and-protected-methods . Basically `private` methods are available to subclasses and it acts more like `protected` in other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* an instance of the controller, instantiated by the framework, per-request.

And yes, subclasses can access the method (as running it would show).

Comment: ah good call, I hadn't noticed at the top it is saying CartsController is inheriting from ApplicationContorller.