# The difference between protected and private methods

Tags: ruby, oop, inheritance, private, protected

In the program below, the child class method calls the parent class' private and protected methods.

```
class Parent  
  private
    def private_method
      'Private Method'
    end
  protected
    def protected_method
      'Protected Method'
    end
end

class Child < Parent
  def get_parent_name
    puts private_name
    puts protected_method
    puts Parent.new.protected_method
    puts Parent.new.private_method    #Throws an error
  end
end

obj = Child.new
obj.get_parent_name
```

The line

```
puts Parent.new.private_method    #Throws an error
```

throws an error. The difference I got is that a private method cannot be accessed using explicit receiver, but a protected method can. If this is the only difference between the private and protected methods, and both can be called in sub classes, then what is the use of these methods compared to other languages like java?

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534449/why-does-ruby-have-both-private-and-protected-methods

Comment: My question is what is the use of private and protected methods if only the difference is of instance?

Comment: You are saying both protected and private methods can be called in sub classes, but in your example calling a private method of the parent in the subclass throws an error. that's the purpose of private and protected. Protected access is used when objects need to access the internal state of other objects of the
same class, but not private methods

Comment: Can you please give an example as I didn't get your answer

Comment: This link provides a good explanation with comparison to other languages and providing examples: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes#Declaring_Visibility